# How STATIC LINK FreeImage Library?

Tags: static-linking, freeimage

This is for people using FreeImage Library - an open source C library to manage images:
http://freeimage.sourceforge.net/

This question has been submitting many times in different forums, but I couldn't find the answer.
If somebody knows the soulution please submit.

I want to use this Library as STATIC library instead of using additional *.dll file.
Unfortunately I Iam getting "unresolved external symbol".

In FreeImage FAQ there is a topic:
How to use FreeImage as a static library instead of as a DLL (Visual C++ 6) ?
http://freeimage.sourceforge.net/faq.html

Unfortunately it doesn't work, because I am recieving "unresolved external symbol" message
even if there is only one "FreeImage_Initialise()" function
I am working in MS VC++ 2008 and 2010 Express.

So I am asking for help. I noted that many people had this same problem.

Maybe is just a question of proper options in MS Visual project?

Answer (score 3):

I think I found the answer myself.

Because the FreeImage solution under VC++ 2008 can't open under VC++ 2010 I created static .lib file
in VC++ 2008 version. Linkin it with project in VC++ 2010 gave error: unresolved external symbol,

but then I tried to link it under a project in VC++ 2008 and it linked successfully.

It seems that static libs from VC++ 2008 works bad in 2010, maybe its VC++ Express 2010 bug...

Answer (score 0):

I used Visual 2012 express and it work fine! FreeImage has been wrapper for .NET, so you must use it in .NET project, not in VC++. This is not Bug.